# Check if currency conversion file is consistent

Tags: algorithm, graph, currency

This was asked in an interview. You are given a file containing the currency conversion rates.

```
Sample File :  
Currency1      Currency2      Rate  
USD            INR            50
GBP            INR            100  
GBP            USD            3       
....
```

We need to tell if this file is consistent or not? eg for the above file to be consistent, the third record should be GBP->USD = 2 instead of 3. How to approach to this problem? Is this a graph problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a graph problem.

A table is consistent if for any pair of currencies (A, B) ANY path of conversions will always give the same rate.

So what you are trying to find is two paths that give you different rate.

Assuming that you have a connected graph (you can convert from anything to anything, maybe via some intermediary currency). You can just pick any start currency then expand it like via DepthFirstSearch or BreadthFirstSearch (doesn't really matter which one here) and compute the rates. If you reach a currency you haven't seen before store the rate you got, if you reached it already the rates must be the same (otherwise stop and say it's inconsistent).

If you you don't have a connected graph you should make sure you've covered all the currencies. You can use the algorithm above, just start it again as long as you can find unreached currencies (using the unreached currency as the start point).

A few things to note:

- You do have some implicit rates. In your talbe INR to USD has a rate of 0.02
- The rates combine by multiplying. Make sure you compare floats correctly (expect some small differences).

Since you can multiply things together for crafted examples you might get really large or really small values and it will make the comparisons harder. A better way to deal with situations like this is to take the log (base doesn't matter) of the numbers. Now the multiplication is replaced by addition and it's more stable. Side effect is that additions and subtractions are much faster than multiplications and divisions.